# Can I opt out of employer-sponsored health insurance?

Tags: united-states, benefits, insurance

I'm in the US.

I'm happy to say that my employer offers a quality health insurance plan using a nationwide carrier. My only option is to opt in to a lower deductible with a higher premium -- same carrier.

Unfortunately, the carrier in question has very little in-network coverage where I live. Since joining this company in August 2022, I have had to pay nearly $5000 out of pocket to cover medical expenses due to the use of out-of-network providers.

Certainly I could change providers, but to be honest, I don't want to. A few reasons:

- My family and I have 10+ year established relationships with our doctors.
- There are very few nearby in-network providers that are well reviewed. I would need to travel much farther for each appointment.

  - This is largely because there is a local university with which almost all nearby providers are affiliated, and the university's providers do not participate with my insurance carrier. The university tends to acquire all of the good providers in the region and bring them into their network.
- Even when we go to in-network providers, they sometimes send lab work to out of network providers, and then I get a surprise bill for the lab work. Last time this happened, I owed $500. Thankfully, I am well paid and we were able to absorb that cost.

My wife is a stay-at-home mom, so there is not another source of employer-sponsored coverage.

I think that there is a rule (part of the Affordable Care Act?) saying that if my employer offers health insurance, I am required to use it. But I don't see any point in doing this; it is worth approximately nothing to me.

I would like to seek private coverage, separate from my employer's offering, but I think I'm going to run into hurdles. I don't really know how any of this works, and in my attempts to research it myself, I find that the search engines are all cluttered with unrelated results, so I've been unable to find the answers I need.

So, my question: can I opt out of employer-sponsored health insurance in favor of a private policy? If I can, are there hurdles I should expect?

Comment: This seems like a good question, but not really one about the workplace.  It might be closed because of that.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure whether it would be applicable. I found some other health-insurance-related questions on this site. If it needs to be closed for this reason, I totally understand -- but I would appreciate pointers to better places to ask! I'm pretty stumped.

Comment: @JakeRobb : [law.se](https://law.stackexchange.com/) maybe?

Comment: Questions about U.S. health insurance are generally on-topic at [Money SE](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-insurance+united-states).

Comment: Your employer's coverage isn't costing you anything, right? Then what is the benefit to you of declining it? You can just take out additional insurance as needed.

Comment: This sounds like something you need to ask your specific HR department about opting out.  I found this article about opting out and using the ACA instead: https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/can-i-buy-health-insurance-the-exchange-rather-signing-employers-insurance.html#:~:text=Obamacare%20is%20available%20to%20everyone,not%20their%20employers%20offer%20insurance.

Comment: My employer subsidizes 100% of the premiums for the lower-cost of the two options; I can opt to pay more in exchange for lower deductibles. (No point whatsoever in doing that, since it doesn't help when I'm out of network.)

Answer (score 4):

> I think that there is a rule (part of the Affordable Care Act?) saying that if my employer offers health insurance, I am required to use it.

That is simply incorrect. You can purchase insurance on the ACA marketplace whether you are eligible for your employer's plan or not.

This might help: https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/can-i-buy-health-insurance-the-exchange-rather-signing-employers-insurance.html

> I would like to seek private coverage, separate from my employer's offering, but I think I'm going to run into hurdles.

No idea what hurdles you are anticipating. But you should get on your state's marketplace and look for a plan. If your state doesn't have their own site, use the federal site at https://www.healthcare.gov/ or just search for insurers covering your area.

> So, my question: can I opt out of employer-sponsored health insurance in favor of a private policy?

Yes.

> If I can, are there hurdles I should expect?

Your employer-sponsored insurance is often subsidized, and thus may well be cheaper than a private plan you purchase on your own. And the plan you choose likely wouldn't come with a government subsidy.

I suppose that could be considered a "hurdle".

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I seem to remember there can be some issues with having multiple Health insurance policies - e.g. Company A will decline because they think Company B should pay and vice versa - if OP did have a private plan and couldn't opt-out of the company insurance, could they run into this issue?

Comment: "No idea what hurdles you are anticipating" -- Mostly, the one you told me was simply incorrect!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can decline health insurance from your employer. Almost all employers have an annual benefits enrollment event, where you can simply opt out or not renew. You may have to wait  until the next event.
2. You can enroll at your state's insurance marketplace even if your employer offers health insurance. Make sure you look at the timing, it's typically once a year unless there is a qualifying event.
3. The insurance marketplace will be expensive with a confusing number of plans (bronze, silver, gold, gold plus, platinum all from different providers) with confusing rules, exclusions, network, and coverage details. A lot of this is smoke and mirrors, in my experience some of these plans were utterly horrible and  bordered on fraud.  Make sure that you study and research this VERY carefully before signing up.
4. There aren't a lot of other options for private insurance (at least in my neck of the wood). An interesting ones are Health Shares (look it up if interested).
5. Some states still dish out stiff  tax penalties for not being properly insured. Make sure you understand the rules for your state.
6. It is definitely worth looking into paying some stuff yourself. Some health care providers will give steep discounts to self-payers. The mechanics behind that are somewhat complicated beyond the scope of this question but, for example, we pay less than half the sticker price for our annual physical.